# Dynamicaly change font-size in SSR Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Trying to build image carousel with interval of 15 sec, fetching all data from the api, i have h1 with the height 228px or 14.25rem, and some of the text overflow the container height i want to reduce the font-size to 50px for each text that overflows the container, but when i am trying to use it the first fetched text returns good value the other one returns undefined, i think the problem is in ssr and trying to accces scrollHeight and clientHeight data on server thats why response is undefined, mb somebody have the solution of this problem

```
<template>
    <Sidebar :index="index" :counter="counter" />
    <div class="hero-header absolute grid grid-cols-2 h-4/6 w-[100%]">
        <div class="col_1 w-[100%]">
            <div v-for="anime in header[index].anime" :key="anime" class="header relative left-[14%] top-[25%] ">
                <h1 ref="animeTitle" class="anime-title w-[38.4rem] h-[14.25rem] leading-[133%] text-[86px] md:text-[50px]">{{ anime.name }}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col_2">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="backg-overlay absolute z-[-1] top-0 left-0 h-screen w-screen"></div>
    <img :src="header[index].banner" alt="banner" class="background-image absolute z-[-2] top-0 left-0 h-screen w-screen" />
</template>



<script setup>
import Sidebar from "~/components/ui/sidebar/Sidebar.vue";

definePageMeta({
    layout: 'default'
})

const { data: header } = await useFetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data/header')
const { data: animeList } = await useFetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data/animeList')

let index = ref(0)
let counter = [0, 1, 2, 3]
const animeTitle = ref(null);

const titleChecker = () => {
    if(process.client) {
        console.log(animeTitle._rawValue);
        console.log(animeTitle._rawValue.clientHeight);
        console.log(animeTitle._rawValue.scrollHeight);

        const containerHeight = animeTitle._rawValue.clientHeight;
        const textHeight = animeTitle._rawValue.scrollHeight;
        let fontSize = 86;
        if (textHeight > containerHeight && fontSize > 50) {
            fontSize = 50;
            animeTitle._rawValue.style.fontSize = `${fontSize}px`;
        }
    }
}

watch(
    () => header._rawValue[index.value].anime[0].name,
    (newVal, oldVal) => {
        if (newVal !== oldVal)
            titleChecker()
    })

onMounted(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
        index.value = (index.value + 1) % 3
    }, 3000)
})
</script>
```

I would like to have carousel with images and text changes accrding to image and if text overflows h1 height font-size should be equal 50 then after change font-size set to 86px and if text fits normal the font-size should remain 86px

I was trying to use nextTick, write the data according to old vue syntax witout setup tag, but the best result i got is that all the text was going smaller because first one overflows the container